# Unknown timestamp format

Tags: timestamps

I do not understand the time encoding of the first line below. I got it in a sample record file and I just have the number but I don't know how it transforms into the corresponding time.

This is the data record:

```
Number:7499969
REC:1:Procedure Start Time: 7499969 (02:04:59.969 UTC)
```

As you can see, I only have a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks suspiciously like the number of milliseconds since midnight of that day.

```
$ echo $((7499969/1000))
7499

$ echo $((2*60*60 + 4*60 + 59))
7499
```

Comment: @Óscar If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.